# What is the force of prefixes on perfective and imperfective verbs? Are all prefixed verbs perfective?

Tags: глаголы, приставки

So you have the perfective and imperfective form of verbs, e.g. дарить и подарить.
This is sometimes determined by the prefix, as shown above.
But verbs can also have other prefixes which determine meaning (I’ll refer to these as special “prefix meanings”, as I don't know what else to call them), e.g. ходить и уходить.

So, does this mean that only the perfective  form of the verb can have a special “prefix meaning”, or does it just mean that verbs for which the prefix changes for the perfective (first example) cannot have a special “prefix meaning”.
Is it possible for imperfective verbs to have a "prefix meaning"? or would giving an imperfect verb a prefix automatically make it a perfective verb?

Comment: I'll let the natives answer this question, but I'll point out that verbs of motion play by different rules in Russian. Unprefixed verbs of motion have two imperfective forms (unidirectional идти and multidirectional ходить) and normally form the perfective by means of the prefix по- added to the unidirectional (пойти). However, once a directional prefix is added, they act just like any other verb with one imperfective form (уходить) and one perfective (уйти).

Comment: In terms of non-verbs of motion, a meaningful prefix such as **о**- (about, around) can be added to say -ПИС- (write) to convey the meaning of *describing*. Without this prefix, that meaning is lost, so both the perfective and imperfective have to have it. Russian resolves this by means of an infix for the imperfective:  **о-пис-áть** (perfective) and **о-пи́с-ыв-ать** (imperfective) *to describe*.

Comment: @CocoPop: do you want to turn it into an answer?

Comment: Sure, if you think it's acceptable.

Comment: @CocoPop, that's a good way to make the verb imperfective again while preserving the meaning brought by a prefix.

Comment: I struggle to understand your questions. "So, does this mean that only the perfective form of the verb can have a special “prefix meaning”" - your example ходить/уходить shows the opposite, isn't it? "уходить" is imperfective.

Comment: @CocoPop I encourage you just like Quassnoi - this is an honest answer material )

Comment: Thank you both. I've added an answer.

Comment: @il--ya: I've edited the title to reflect the gist of the actual question more accurately.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of non-verbs of motion, a meaningful prefix such as **о-** (*about, around*) can be added to the stem -ПИС- (write), for example, to convey the meaning of *describing*. Without this prefix, that meaning is lost, so both the perfective and imperfective have to have it. Russian resolves this by means of an infix for the imperfective: **о-пис-áть** (perfective) and **о-пи́с-ыв-ать** (imperfective) *to describe*.

Verbs of motion play by different rules in Russian. Unprefixed verbs of motion have two imperfective forms (unidirectional **идти** and multidirectional **ходить**) and normally form the perfective by means of the prefix **по-** added to the unidirectional (**пойти**). However, once a directional prefix is added to a verb of motion, it acts just like any other verb with one imperfective form (**уходить**) and one perfective (**уйти**).

Answer (score 1):

There is, of course, a correlation between the aspects and prefixes. Prefixes are usually used to form perfectives from imperfective verb forms. But there are so many exceptions that it's easy to get frustrated.

Consider the verbs of movement that you mentioned:

```
идти
ходить
```

How easy would it be to derive prefixed imperfective derivatives from these two? (To contradict the rule).

```
проходить
переходить
выходить
сходить
```

And I cannot think of any prefixed form of `идти`, which is also imperfective.

So I wouldn't rely on prefixes when trying to form perfectives. Prefixes can give you a semantic and aspectual hint, but the actual meaning is often semantic, not grammatical.

Comment: Prefixed perfective forms of _идти_ are _пройти, перейти, выйти, сойти_ and many others. Iterative verbs of motion (like _ходить_) with a prefix can form both perfective and imperfective verbs, differing, if at all, only in stress. In your example, that would be _что делать? переходить_ "to cross (a road)" or _что сделать? переходить_ "to fix an invalid move (in a board game)". I can't think of a perfective meaning for _проходить_, but all the other verbs in your example do have both meanings.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Wouldn't the perfective of проходить be пройти? For instance: Только после того, как она прошла мимо солдат, она испустила дух. She didn't realease her breath until after she had passed the soldiers. No?

Comment: @CocoPop: it would, why? Btw, _испустить дух_ means "to give up the ghost, to die". Did you mean _перевела дух_?

Comment: @Quassnoi: Because above you said "I can't think of a perfective meaning for проходить."

Comment: @CocoPop: I meant this very form, _проходить_. _Переходить_ is both perfective and imperfective, _проходить_ is not

Comment: @Quassnoi: Oh, I see now. Ok)))